# Swift/Alamofire: Iterating through JSON values to check for bool value?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Here is the JSON:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "season",
      "id": "season.1",
      "attributes": {
        "isCurrentSeason": true,
        "isOffseason": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "season",
      "id": "season2",
      "attributes": {
        "isCurrentSeason": false,
        "isOffseason": false
      }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through this JSON data to see if isCurrentSeason is true. If it is true, I need to store the "id" of it.

Here is my current implementation:

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let _data):
                print(_data)
                if let DataObject = _data["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let Attributes = DataObject["attributes"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                        for attribute in Attributes {
                            if Attributes["isCurrentSeason"] = true {
                                currentSeasonID = Attributes["isCurrentSeason"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

I keep getting the error `Pattern cannot match values of type 'Result<Any>'` on the case .Success line. So I can't even test if it is pulling the correct data. Not sure if there is a better way to iterate and record through the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use `NSDictionary` in place of Swift's `Dictionary`. Secondly you are not casting `data` with the same type that is returned in response. It should be an `array` of `dictionary` while you are casting it as `dictionary` where it will always fail. I am not sure which version of Alamofire you are using but in the current version the enum `Result<Any>` success case is camelCase i.e, `.success(let data)`. If you get an error then use the one you already have i.e, `.Success(let data)`. Below is the fixed version,

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
    typealias JSON = [String: Any]
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        guard let json = data as? JSON, let objects = json["data"] as? [JSON] else { return }
        for object in objects {
            if let attributes = object["attributes"] as? JSON,
                let currentSession = attributes["isCurrentSeason"] as? Bool,
                currentSession == true {
                print(currentSession)
                print(object["id"] as! String)
                break
            }
        }
    default:
        print("Error occured")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that `_data` – by the way variables with leading underscore is very *objective-c-ish* – is `Any` so you have to conditional downcast already this type. if the expected type is a dictionary consider to use more specific `Result<[String:Any]>`.

Please read the JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only two collection types, array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`), so the value for key `data` is an array and the value for key `attributes` is a dictionary

And please conform to the naming convention that variables start with a lowercase letter and don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift.

```
switch response.result {

        case .Success(let response):

            if let response = response as? [String:Any],
               let data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
               for item in data {
                   if let attributes = item["attributes"] as? [String:Bool],
                      let isCurrentSeason = attributes["isCurrentSeason"], isCurrentSeason == true {
                         currentSeasonID = isCurrentSeason
                         break // add this to exit the loop immediately if the item was found
                   }
               }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
```

However I guess `currentSeasonID` is supposed to be the `id` value rather then the boolean  `isCurrentSeason`

```
        case .Success(let response):

            if let response = response as? [String:Any],
               let data = response["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
               for item in data {
                   if let identifier = item["id"] as? String,
                      let attributes = item["attributes"] as? [String:Bool],
                      let isCurrentSeason = attributes["isCurrentSeason"], isCurrentSeason == true {
                         currentSeasonID = identifier
                         break // add this to exit the loop immediately if the item was found
                   }
               }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
if let content =  _data as? [String:Any] {
    if let dataObject = content["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            dataObject.forEach {
             if let attributes = $0["attributes"] as? [String:Bool] { 
                if attributes["isCurrentSeason"] == true { 
                    print("This is true")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `data` is an array of dictionaries , and `attributes` is a dictionary

Comment: I'm getting an: Type 'Any' has no subscript members, error on the case .success. Any idea why?

Comment: @David `_data` is of type `Any` so it should be casted to `[String:Any]` see edit